# Are there two ways to create objects in java?

Tags: java, class, object, initialization

What is the difference between

```
ClassABC objectName = new ClassABC();
```

and

```
ClassABC objectName = differentVariable.methodReturnsClassABCTypeValue();
```

Is the second example still initiated like the first? And if no, what are the differences between these two types of "initilizations"?

If this is confusing, I will give a second example using another Java Class.

```
Toolkit toolKitObject = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension screenSize = new Dimension();
```

and

```
Toolkit toolKitObject = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension screenSize = toolKitObject.getScreenSize();
```

Notice how in the first example I created the Dimension object and did not set any value to it.. but in the second example, I never used  `new Dimension();` I immediately went ahead and did `toolKitObject.getScreenSize();`

Comment: Sorry, i had to edit this a bit. 

The second one is the same class as the first, but in its object I am storing the value of a method that returns a value that can be stored in the ClassABC object.

Comment: `methodReturnsClassABCTypeValue()` must have `new ClassABC()` somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your examples end up using the `new` operator.

```
Dimension screenSize = toolKitObject.getScreenSize();
```

Here's the source code of `getScreenSize` you're calling in the above line:

```
// implementation as per SunToolkit.class
public Dimension getScreenSize() {
    return new Dimension(getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight());
}
```

You'll see that behind the scenes, it's still calling a `new Dimension` (the overloaded version that takes height and width).

Answer (score 13):

There are [different](http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2007/09/13/different-ways-to-create-objects/) ways to create objects in java:

A. Using new keyword This is the most common way to create an object in java. Almost 99% of objects are created in this way.

```
MyObject object = new MyObject();
```

B. Using Class.forName() If we know the name of the class & if it has a public default constructor we can create an object in this way.

```
MyObject object = (MyObject) Class.forName("subin.rnd.MyObject").newInstance();
```

C. Using clone() The clone() can be used to create a copy of an existing object.

```
MyObject anotherObject = new MyObject();
MyObject object = anotherObject.clone();
```

D. Using object deserialization Object deserialization is nothing but creating an object from its serialized form.

```
ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(anInputStream );
MyObject object = (MyObject) inStream.readObject();
```

E. Using reflection in another way.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(“com.abc.myobject”).newInstance();
```

Comment: Great compilation here! I would easily assume there were only 2, 3 tops. By the way isn't B and E just the same, since you finish up using `newInstance` in the end?

Comment: @Ronixus No, they are similar but not same.[getClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader()) and [forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3):

I like the answer by Achintya, but I have the feeling the answer is way more advanced than the question.

In java, a variable (excluding primitive types, such as integer) *references* an object in memory.

Therefore, the following snippet creates just one object which is referenced by two different variables:

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = a;
```

The same thing happens in your examples, though in a more hidden way.

The following snippet creates a `Toolkit` object. This object contains, among others, a `Dimension` object. The second line just creates a reference to that already existing object.

```
Toolkit toolKitObject = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension screenSize = toolKitObject.getScreenSize();
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. 

So one last thing then.. 

What is `screenSize` now technically?

Comment: No buddy, that's not entirely correct, please see the extracted source code of getScreensize, it does NOT reference an existing Dimension variable in the ToolKit object. It creates a new one. See my answer.

Comment: I (the OP) saw your response. It was very clear and explained my question. I suppose I have one question left.. say that `getScreenSize();` method did NOT create a new `Dimension` object.. say it did something different but did NOT create an object.. would `screenSize` be just a variable.. it would not be an object, right? Since no object is created.. can you explain that?

Comment: @Ronixus ah ok, I admit that I didn't check the `Toolkit`, but it would have been possible that way ;-)

Comment: @Heuster No worries buddy, just clarifying. :) Yes it would have been possible just the same.

Comment: @Draconian every object must be created somewhere, using one of the 4 methods that Achintya described. What I was expecting (and turned out to be wrong by Ronixus) is that in `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` the object was created (using `new Dimension()`) and assigned to a class variable of `Toolkit`, such that it can be returned later by `getScreenSize()`.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.!!
2nd one does NOT create an object. It gets an object created from another method. If that method creates a new Object, then it's fine. If that method uses an existing method, no.

Answer (score 0):

At below line

```
ClassABC objectName = new ClassABC();
```

its creates new Instance on heap and new reference on stack and assigning this new Objects reference to new reference created.
. 
So with this code we will definately getting new object on heap. so after above line objectName will never be null for sure.

But with this

```
ClassABC objectName = differentVariable.methodReturnsClassABCTypeValue()
```

we are creating only new reference on stack. and poitning it to existing Object on heap which might be created/referenced inside method.

so at this stage it will definately create reference on stack. but new Object created on heap or not depends on the implementation of the method.

so after above line objectName can be null or not null depending on whats returned from method. .
Hope it clears the things.